# Conditional probability distribution $p(A | A + B > C)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Consider three independent normally distributed variables: *A*, *B*, *C*. How would you calculate the distribution $p(A | A + B > C)$?

I know that the distribution $p(A + B | A + B > C) = p(A+B) \times CDF(C)/s$, where *s* is a normalising factor, but I'm not sure whether it is possible to use this to calculate what *A* is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since the r.v. are independent then:

$$
p_A(u\mid A+B>C) \; = \; \dfrac { p_A(u)\; \mathsf P(B+u > C) }{ \mathsf P(B+A>C)}
$$

Can you calculate the two probabilities ?: $\mathsf P(B+u > C), \mathsf P(B+A > C)$

Comment: I can calculate those two probabilities:
$$P(A + B > C) = P(A + B - C > 0) = \int_{-\infty}^{0} p(A + B - C)$$
$$P(u + B > C) = P(B - C > -u) = \int_{-\infty}^{-u} p(B - C)$$

Comment: So then I end up with something of the form:

$$p_{A}(u|A+B>C) = \frac{p_{A}(u)f(u)}{\textrm{constant}}$$

Comment: Just realised the integrals in the previous comment should be from 0 to infinity and -u to infinity respectively.

Comment: Ok, so I've just worked through it and it comes out to the same results as using a Monte Carlo method. Thanks for the help!